# Call Azure DB SQL stored procedure using web service, api, .. from mobile app

Tags: web-services, api, azure, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

I am trying to build a mobile application that needs data from an Azure SQL DB. Best practice looks like building a web service in between.

However I am getting lost in the number of solutions.

**Which specific Azure component do I need to use to have a future-proof solid solution?
How to handle security between this component and the Azure SQL DB?
How to handle security between the mobile application and the Azure Component?**

Comment: More than likely this post will be closed because the questions you asked are pretty broad in nature and there are many solutions to these problems. My recommendation would be to try some things out and ask very specific questions. HTH.

Comment: I hope I could already be pointed in some good directions or learn about the diferent options. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

The best way forward is to use an ASP.NET Web API with ADO Entity Frameworks and publish the API to an Azure website. Use REST services to call the Web Api from your mobile app.

So basically:

1) Fire up VS and build a Web Api that will handle your database using ADO Entity Framework and the controller for your API. Check this: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-tutorials

2) Publish the Web Api to an Azure website/app through VS. Make sure you have Azure services installed on your VS.

3) Call the Web Api from your mobile app using REST services to work with the SQL database. You will need an HttpClient class to do this, you can get it from NuGet.

For security of your Web API, check this: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security